# How to set Entity Framework data to JavaScript variables?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have a website that uses ASP.NET MVC, and I store my data using Entity Framework.

Here is what one of my Razor View Pages looks like:

```
@model IEnumerable<GPBuddy.DataContexts.Item.History>

@{
    String arr = "";
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        arr += item.current_price_raw.ToString() + ",";
    }
    arr = arr.TrimEnd(',');
}

<div id="testData">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var array = '@arr';
    var prices = array.split(",");
    text = "<ul>"
    for (i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        text += "<li>" + prices[i] + "</li>";
    }
    text += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

UPDATED: We are now able to set JavaScript variables to EF variable data.

Here is what the html looks like:

```
<div id="testData">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var array = '2051,2034,1908,1908,1887,1887,1680,1610,1549,1452,1411,1421,1439,1464,1533,1608,1763,1958,2027,2070,2077,2043,2026,2026,2013';
    var prices = array.split(",");
    text = "<ul>"
    for (i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        text += "<li>" + prices[i] + "</li>";
    }
    text += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, you don't really need any JavaScript here as far as I can tell, you could output the price list using Razor syntax.

Comment: You can't confuse what is happening in JavaScript with what is being rendered in HTML. Take a look at your rendered HTML and if you uncomment out the @index you will see that it renders 0++ which will not work. I can go into detail if you need to but I believe if you check out the rendered code it will make sense to you.

Comment: @CraigSelbert I see what you are saying. I realized that since the c# stuff is server side and the javascript is client side, it's as if the c# runs once and then javascript takes over with it's own processing. I currently have a work around. About to post

Comment: @Chris I'm trying to capture the data in Java script so I can use it in a graphing library. (sorry I must've removed that part from post!) :D

Comment: @Jasoon Please see my revised answer. I have made numerous improvements on your updated code.

Comment: @Dai They have been implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want this:

```
var array = [ @( String.Join( ", ", this.Model.Select( i => i.current_price_raw ) ) ];
```

Your original code has problems, which my single-line solution above avoids:

- Concatenating `System.String` in a loop is bad for performance (with geometric runtime complexity because each string concatenation (of `n` and `m` characters in length) and allocates `n+m` on every iteration.

  - Use `String.Join` to create a comma-separated list, this also avoids needing to `Trim` any trailing comma (`Trim` also creates a new string allocation too).
- Your JavaScript code was rendered without the JavaScript literal-array syntax (`[x,y,z]`), your original rendered code was just declaring a series of literal integer expressions.
- You can use Linq to make code more succinct with zero (or negligible) performance impact (in my case, using `Select` instead of `foreach`).

I will say that writing JavaScript and JSON in Razor is difficult because they both use curley-braces as delimiters, this was a lot easier with ASPX `<%=` delimiters.

### Update:

Your code to extract individual elements is inefficient because you're splitting a string and doing string-to-int conversion, that's useless. Your code will be significantly faster (and easier to read) if you use native JavaScript arrays like in my original example. You should also use the DOM API instead of generating HTML in text. Here is my version of your follow-on code:

```
var array = [ @(String.Join( ",", this.Model.Select( i => i.current_price_raw ) ) ) ];

var ul = document.createElement("ul");

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = array[i].toString();

    ul.appendChild( li );
}

document.getElementById("testData").appendChild( ul );
```

- `string.split` is an expensive operation
- JavaScript string concatenation can also be expensive. Different JS runtimes (V8 vs Chakra etc) implement strings differently and "cheap concatenation" is never guaranteed. I am annoyed JavaScript does not have a `StringBuilder` equivalent.
- Forming HTML using string concatenation is inherently dangerous the same way generating SQL with concatenation is: if you have any user-input which is not properly sanitized (or even if it is sanitized) you run the risk of XSS and other code-injection attacks.
- Another reason to avoid HTML-as-strings and using `innerHTML` is that it invokes the browser's HTML parser, which is not cheap. By using the DOM API directly (`document.createElement`, `element.appendChild`, etc) you avoid the parser completely and so maximize performance. Use `innerHTML` only when appropriate (such as when using the DOM API might be unwieldy).

### Update 2:

As the first commentator points out, if you're not going to be using your data in another script it's faster to render it directly in Razor:

```
<ul>
@foreach(var item in this.Model) {
    <li>@( item.current_price_raw )</li>   
}
</ul>
```

Comment: I was only listing the data in order to figure out and verify that my EF data was being transferred to JavaScript. My next step will be using this data in Chart.js to create graphs. Awesome post